# In org-mode is there a way create a table of contents from a directory structure of org files?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to create a "landing page" to act as an entry point for my org files. Ideally this landing page would contain links that automatically update every time a new org file is added or edited. It would be great if the links could be organised in a way that preserves some of the directory heirarchy (like a table of contents).

Is this possible in org-mode? If so, how would I go about it?

EDIT: something in a similar vein to [doctoc](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc) but for org files and directories. I want it to traverse the given directory, import the `#+TITLE:`s and display them (possibly in some kind of tree structure that mirrors the directory structure).

Comment: Can you add a simple example (a small directory hierarchy with a handful of directories and a handful of files - not only Org mode files, unless your "real" hierarchy will *only* include Org mode files) and what the "landing page" Org mode file would look like? In particular, if an existing file is changed, what information on the landing page would reflect that change? There is probably nothing built-in that would come even close to what (I imagine) you are describing, so it'd have to be built. And the syncing part in particular would be tedious to do in Emacs - it'd need help from the OS.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a file manager, supporting tree view.

Comment: @nichijou Like e.g. [treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs).

Comment: @Fergie or if you'd realy prefer the 'landing page' then it would be handy to know why (this is preferred over the tree-browser). Anyway, in that case, I think the problem should be quite easy to solve (and we could help think about a solution)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback- see my EDIT in the original question

Comment: From 'doctoc', I understand it only updates TOC's for and within the individual files, I don't see anything mentioned about a TOC resembling the directory tree structure. Also, the edited text still does not very much explain why you want the requested functionality...

Comment: I think the OP wants to have an index of his org files automatically created. For example, every folder would be hierarchically represented by a headline and every org file by an `org-link` pointing to it. For example, if a folder named Alpha contains 10 org files, this will be represented in the index by a headline name Alpha containing a list of 10 `org-link`. Am I right @Fergie?

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but then there was the part about *editing* a file and have that reflected in the landing page: if a file is represented by a link, changes to it could not be represented: editing the file would not change the link. The OP wants the title of the document in the landing page (presumably linkified). BTW `doctoc` does not seem to update the toc automatically: you have to invoke it explicitly I think.

Comment: @crocefisso yes that is right

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script in your preferred programming language. Here is a naive idea. I'm sure it could be improved since I'm no developer.

Suppose `~/tmp/` is the entry point for your org files:

```bash
$ tree ~/tmp/
~/tmp/
├── Abc
│   ├── Alef
│   │   └── alef.org
│   └── Bet
│       ├── beta.org
│       └── bet.org
├── testing.org
├── test.org
└── tmp.org
```

You could build a script based on `find` results:

```bash
$ find ~/tmp/
~/tmp/
~/tmp/test.org
~/tmp/Abc
~/tmp/Abc/Bet
~/tmp/Abc/Bet/beta.org
~/tmp/Abc/Bet/bet.org
~/tmp/Abc/Alef
~/tmp/Abc/Alef/alef.org
~/tmp/testing.org
~/tmp/tmp.org
```

- Write `* tmp`
- Skip first line
- If a line contains an extension that is not `.org`, discard the line
- If a line contains a `.org` extension, write `- [[`content of the line`][`content of the line after the last `/`, minus extension`]]`
- If a line doesn't contain an extension, write `*` then write `*` for every `/` after `tmp`, then write a `space`, then write the term before the last `/`.

This script will produce:

```
* tmp
- [[~/tmp/test.org][test]]
** Abc
*** Bet
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Bet/beta.org][beta]]
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Bet/bet.org][bet]]
*** Alef
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Alef/alef.org][alef]]
- [[~/tmp/testing.org][testing]]
- [[~/tmp/tmp.org][tmp]]
```

There is an issue though, the proper output should be that instead:

```
* tmp
- [[~/tmp/test.org][test]]
- [[~/tmp/testing.org][testing]]
- [[~/tmp/tmp.org][tmp]]
** Abc
*** Bet
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Bet/beta.org][beta]]
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Bet/bet.org][bet]]
*** Alef
- [[~/tmp/Abc/Alef/alef.org][alef]]
```

In order to solve this issue, one has to find a way to have `find` printing its results according to some hierarchical order.